# Is it professional to have a "cited by" section of a personal website?

Tags: citations, website

I'm not sure if there's a word or phrase for a "reverse bibliography", but that's what I'm looking to put on my website - a list of other papers that have cited my own work. The goal is to show that my work has had influence and has spread beyond just the paper itself. Is this common in academia, or is it only common to list one's own papers?

Comment: How about creating a google scholar account? Then people can easily look up that information.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For any well established research, they will usually have quite a large number of citations, which would make a "cited by" section would be exhausting to maintain and large beyond meaningful readability.  A better route is to link to an database that actually engages in curating ones citations, such as Google Scholar.

I do, however, sometimes see people maintaining a collection of notable articles in non-scientific media.  These are not normally picked up by citation databases and are valuable for showing that work is having impact *outside of* the scientific community, as well as (sometimes) providing a nice introduction to the work.

Comment: Very interesting, I'll look into Google Scholar as an option.

Comment: Regarding "maintaining a collection of notable articles in non-scientific media", I know my advisor keeps a section similar to this in which he lists TV, and radio interviews conducted with him.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on @jakebeal's answer: If you can still list all citations you have ever received, then the number of citations you have received is so small that the attempt reflects negatively. Most reasonably well established scientists have thousands of citations to their credit. It becomes impossible to list them all. The list also often grows by a dozen a week, more than you probably want to keep up.

As already noted, the solution lies in linking to a referencing service such as google scholar or MathSciNet.

Comment: I agree with linking to a referencing service, but this is somewhat field dependent.  The median number of citations for a pure math paper is 0, and the very top journals have IFs around 3.  There are National Academy members with "only" a few hundred total citations.  It is a significant (though also very noisy) indicator for someone applying for a tenure-track job to have been cited, and even more significant if they've been cited more than a dozen times (though subfields vary quite a bit in both paper writing and citation practices, so interpretation requires care).

Comment: A dozen a week means in 2 years you get > 1000 citations... isn't that a heck of a lot? Sounds like a rarity even among professors...

Comment: @AlexanderWoo That's why the very first thing a hiring committee does is to look up all the applicants on MathSciNet to make a table of the number of papers and of citations. This can be a problem in applied maths, where MathSciNet a) doesn't list the more application-focused journals and b) has a backlog of months to years, but should be more accurate for the lower-volume pure maths fields you are referring to. Google Scholar is way too noisy to be relied upon in this context.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo -- one could argue that if you only have a few hundred citations over a lifetime of research, then you're doing things nobody cares about. The same could be said about the median pure math paper. But that's a discussion not worth getting into.

Comment: @Mehrdad -- I don't know. I got 438 citations last year (https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=hmznSQwAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=ao). This is a reasonable number, but I could probably list 2 dozen colleagues within 5 minutes who are significantly above that.

Comment: @ChristianClason -- it's true that Google Scholar lists a lot of things that may or may not be relevant. But I do think that it is a very useful tool when comparing people in the same field against each other.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Only if the person in charge actually takes the trouble to curate the list properly. I could name some colleagues whose impressive citation numbers are due to them sharing last name and initial with an (even more) prominent mathematician. On the other hand, as a first glance to what they've been up to the last year or two, Google Scholar is indeed very useful (and much more so than MathSciNet). Horses for courses.

Comment: @ChristianClason I think that if you choose to refer people to Google Scholar see who you've been cited by, it's clear incumbent upon you to curate your page.

Comment: @jakebeal I agree of course, but my point is that the fact that some people don't limits its usefulness as a tool to compare people against each other (e.g., in the context of a hiring committee). All this is somewhat tangential to the original question, though, since a committee would put even less stock in a self-maintained "cited-by" list, so (properly) maintaining a Google Scholar profile is indeed a reasonable alternative.

Answer (score 2):

*Let turn this round....*

People reading your website may be doing so because they are interested in your research topics.  Therefore assuming you list your papers by topic, it could be very helpful for you to also list papers that expand on your papers in interesting ways, including explaining how they expand on your work in a few sentences.